# Is it possible to use single service of SaaS, IaaS, and PaaS on different Cloud Provider simultaneously?

Tags: cloud, saas, paas, iaas

Is it possible to use single service of SaaS, IaaS, and PaaS on 3 different Cloud Provider and connect them together?for example my company needs Microsoft Cloud Software for their employees, IBM Baremetal for its server and Github PaaS for their IT to help developing backend/script. Microsoft Software, IBM Baremetal and Github is just example they can choose another cloud provider. I know my question is kind of non sense but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It is very possible to link single service of IaaS,Paas and Saas on  3 different cloud providers. Few methods to achieve multi cloud design has been mentioned below:

[1]To connect Google Cloud with other cloud service providers (CSP) such as Amazon Web Services (AWS) and Microsoft Azure.

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/patterns-for-connecting-other-csps-with-gcp

[2]Multi Cloud: Connecting Azure to AWS and GCP

https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/GettingStartedAzureToAWSAndGCP.html